# Adding dates to asp Repeater using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I have two repeaters one nested inside the other.

The first repeater creates 12 rows, one for each month of the year. It works out the number of days for each month in turn and adds them to an array. The array is then used as the datasource for the second repeater.

The second repeater checks the days for each month and sets the background colour of a td if the DayOfWeek is either a Saturday or Sunday. (See second image).

This all works correctly and does what I require.

What I need to do next is query a SQL database table that contains a list of holiday dates. The table contains the Start date of the holiday, the number of days taken and a hex colour code.

What I want it to do is find the start date in rptAbsenceDays_ItemDataBound and using the number of days and the colour value display it similar to the second link. This information is stored in hidden fields.

This is what I am trying to create [image]

This is what I have managed so far [image]

How can I call the StaffAbsence and get it to display the holidays

*Below is the code for my page*

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="Absence">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litYear" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </th>
                <%--Creates a row of 31 days along the top of the repeater--%>
                <% for (int iWeek = 1; iWeek <= 31; iWeek++) { %>
                    <th style="width:30px; text-align:center; background-color:darkgray;"" >
                        <%= iWeek %>
                    </th>
                <% } %>                                           
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAbsenceMonths" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptAbsenceMonths_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litMonth" runat="server" />
                </td>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptAbsenceDays" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptAbsenceDays_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <td id="tdDay" runat="server">
                                <asp:Literal ID="litDay" runat="server" />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidAbsenceStartDate" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScheduleStartDate")%>'/>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidAbsenceTotalDays" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScheduleDays")%>'/>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidAbsenceColour" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScheduleColour")%>'/> 
                            </td>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And this is my C# code

```
    protected void AbsenceMonths()
    {
        litYear.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        rptAbsenceMonths.DataSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
        rptAbsenceMonths.DataBind();

    }

    protected void rptAbsenceMonths_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater rptAbsenceDays = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptAbsenceDays");
            Literal litMonth = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litMonth");
            _currentBindingMonth = (int)e.Item.DataItem;
            _absenceMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, _currentBindingMonth, 1);
            litMonth.Text = _absenceMonth.ToString("MMM");

            int numberOfDays = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt16(litYear.Text), _currentBindingMonth);
            DateTime[] monthdays = new DateTime[numberOfDays];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++)
            {
                monthdays[i] = _absenceMonth;
                _absenceMonth = _absenceMonth.AddDays(1);
            }

            rptAbsenceDays.DataSource = monthdays;
            rptAbsenceDays.DataBind();

        }

    }

}

    protected void rptAbsenceDays_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)e.Item.DataItem;
            Literal litDay = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litDay");
            HtmlTableCell tdDay = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdDay");

            if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                tdDay.Style.Add("background-color", "#D0D0D0");
            }

            tdDay.ID = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected void StaffAbsence(int StaffID, int AbsenceYear)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetStaffAbsence", cnn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpCode", StaffID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", AbsenceYear);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //rptAbsenceDays.DataSource = dt;
            //rptAbsenceDays.DataBind();
            //rptAbsenceDays.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Why not use a GridView? That becomes a table in html. And if you do that you can access the cells by day and month as the x-y coordinates easily.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. You can do that while the repeater is being bound in`rptAbsenceDays_ItemDataBound`, but make sure you have the data for the holidays first.

If you don't want to do that while the repeater is being bound. You can go and loop through the repeater items and then do what ever you need

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptAbsenceDays.Items)
{
     if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || ri.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
         //do your logic here
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding currently not at work so will look at your suggestion when i am back in the office